# VS Code debugger stopped working after migration to src folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js, vscode-debugger

VS code breakpoints stopped working correctly after migrating `app` folder to `src`.

1. Breakpoints work fine for server side code like api calls.
2. Breakpoints stopped working for client-side code. Adding `debugger;` works just fine but VS code breakpoints are not getting mapped correctly and do not work at all.

Tested on two different machines macOS-based and Windows as well. The same issue.

VS code gives the following suggestion:

```
✅ This breakpoint was initially set in:

D:\Projects\BookingWRT\src\app[lang]\components\booking\ExistingBooking.tsx line 28 column 1

✅ In the runtime, the breakpoint was set in:

file:///d:/projects/bookingwrt/src/app/(?:[ line 28 column 1 via this regex

webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./src/app/[lang]/components/booking/ExistingBooking.tsx line 55 column 5

✅ The runtime acknowledged and adjusted the breakpoint, and it mapped back to the following locations:

d:\Projects\BookingWRT\src\app[lang]\components\booking\ExistingBooking.tsx line 28 column 19
If this is not right, your compiled code might be out of date with your sources. If you don't think this is the case and something else is wrong, please open an issue!
```

Also receiving the following in VS Code Debug Console

```
Could not read source map for file:///D:/Projects/BookingWRT/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/%40next/react-refresh-utils/dist/runtime.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Projects\BookingWRT\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\runtime.js.map'
```

**pakacge.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": { "@/*": ["./*"] },
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNEXT",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be caused by the compiled code mapping issue

set

```
"sourceMaps": true,
```

if required set

```
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
```

in your VSCode run configuration
Note:- you may need to clear generated folders like dist/out

try a debugger with the same kind of project if you are facing the same issue then completely uninstall VSCode and reinstall it

Comment: "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/"
],

additionally you can set if changed any thing